# TABLE 1 data needs to populated to table2 by grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I have

### TABLE 1

col1 col2 col3 col4

1    1    1     AP

1    2    1     MP

4    2    1     MP

1    3    1     AP

2    2    2     JP

2    4    2     JP

8    7    2     LP

8    7    2     LP

8    8    3     HP

2    4    3     HP

3    9    3     ZP

6    9    3     ZP

I have a requirement that i have move data from table 1 to Table 2 by satisfying requirements

### TABLE2

### col1 col2 col3 col4

2    3    1    AP

5    2    1    MP

4     4    2   JP

16    7    2   LP

10    8    3   HP

9     9    3   ZP

where values col3 are grouped in such a way that we should sum all the values of col1 and where  as max value of col2 needs to be populated

Any answers or clues will be appriciated

Comment: This is a fairly basic question. Please take a look at `GROUP BY`, plus the `SUM` and `MAX` functions, and try this yourself. If you still have problems post what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT SUM(col1),MAX(col2),col3
FROM table1
GROUP BY col3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

select sum(col1) col1, max(col2) col2, col3 col3
into table2
group by col3

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with nosid's statement? Just make sure to add col4 in the select and group by statements. Does that work?

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT SUM(col1),MAX(col2),col3, col4
FROM table1
GROUP BY col3,col4;
```